# General solution for $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a general solution for

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} x^z$$ 
for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I assume we have to distinguish the cases $\mathrm{Re}[z]=0$, $\mathrm{Re}[z]>0$, $\mathrm{Re}[z]<0$, $\mathrm{Im}[z]=0$, $\mathrm{Im}[z]>0$, $\mathrm{Im}[z]<0$.

The case $\mathrm{Im}[z]=0$ is rather simple:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} x^z = \begin{cases}
\infty \quad \mathrm{Re}[z]<0 \\
1 \,\,\,\quad \mathrm{Re}[z]=0 \\
0 \,\,\,\quad \mathrm{Re}[z]>0
\end{cases}$$

But what are the solutions for the other cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the definition how a number with complex exponent is defined. I'm familiar with
$$
x^z = e^{z\ln(x)}.
$$
Now you can conlcude
$$
x^z = e^{\Re(z)\ln(x)}e^{\Im(z)\ln(x)i}
$$
and you can see what happens. If $\Im(z)=0$ then your angle is $0$ and you have just a real value. But if $\Im(z)\neq 0$ then $x^z$ rotates around $0$. If further $\Re(z)<0$ it goes to $0$. If $\Re(z)=0$ it runs on the unit sphere without limit and if $\Re(z)>0$ it blows up "to infinity".